# GROUP BY in a JOIN?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, group-by, calendar, inner-join

I have a data table and a calendar table.  The date table only contains the fields MonthName and FiscalYearName.  My calendar table has each day for each year.  How can I write the JOIN to make sure I am not getting duplicated data due to the inability to JOIN on a date?  Right now am I just linking on those two fields and I am getting duplicate data.

Comment: well, what result would you want by joining a table with only year and month to one with year, month and date?

Comment: It would be helpful, if you can provide the sample query that your are using

Comment: what's the point of the calendar table in this scenario? Perhaps you are [asking a question about X, but should be asking it about Y](http://xyproblem.info/)... just explain the actual issue you are trying to fix (not the problem with your code) and this may be easier.

Comment: I am trying to return a field that exists in the Calendar table that is not in the Data table.  I only have MonthName in the Data table and I want to return MonthNumber in my query.  MonthNumber is a field in the Calendar table which is why I need to JOIN to it.

Comment: ok then, it would be very helpful to see a sample dataset and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you elaborate on the exact issue?

If month and year are the only fields, why exactly do you need to join on Calendar? To get rid of duplicates, the easiest solution might be to use a 'DISTINCT'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dat.year, dat.month, *
  FROM date dat
  JOIN calendar cal
    ON dat.year  = cal.year
   AND dat.month = cal.month
```

Edit;
Extra query to just show the MonthNum;
This query uses a common table expression which gets the distinct month names and their number only once, then joins the date table on this cte.

```
WITH cteCalendar AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT MonthName, MonthNum FROM calendar
)
SELECT cte.MonthNum, dat.*
FROM date dat
JOIN cteCalendar cte
AS dat.MonthName = cte.MonthName
```

Comment: My issue is needing to return a field that exists on the Calendar table.  I need to return the value for MonthNum.  The data table only contains FiscalYear and MonthName.

Comment: I have added another query which uses a common table expression.
This query basically gets all the month's from the calendar table Once, and then joins this CTE on your date table, thus eliminating the duplicates.